# Berkeley DB Bulk Feature

Tags: c, database, performance, berkeley-db

Hi
I can't find anywhere about Berkeley DB Bulk insert feature written in **C**. I can find about update, select and delete at **http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/am_misc_bulk.html**. Can anybody tell me how to write this bulk insert feature? I'm new to both **C and Berkeley DB.**

- I also want to write quite a lot of data (may be 30GB) using this feature , so please also advise me for the performance too.
- my boss wants me to use Hash access method.

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: Poor you, new to C and tasked to cope with the Berkeley DB API.

Comment: yes !! never heard of Berkeley DB before I come to this company for my internship !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is going to help or hurt given your newness to both C and BerkleyDB.

You would need to use the `DB_MULTIPLE` flag with `DB->put()`.

In order to do this you need to create a bulk `DBT` structure for your keys, and one for your data. The buffers must be large enough to hold the entire set of keys and values accordingly. You then have to initialize both of them with `DB_MULTIPLE_WRITE_INIT`, then add your keys and values to the respective buffer with `DB_MULTIPLE_WRITE_NEXT`.

This was added in 4.8 and honestly, I can't find a concrete example for you via google.

**EDIT:** At least in the latest releases there's example code provided with BerkeleyDB for bulk operations. You need to take a look at `examples/c/ex_bulk.c`

Comment: Hi one more question , I need one DBT for both key and data. right ??? the buffer must be large enough for the keys and values. So does it mean i have to put all my bulk in the keys? Can you elaborate a bit more because I'm confused. I look the ex_bulk but still don't understand it. So sorry about my ignorance .

Comment: You have to load all your keys into one DBT, and all the values into the other (in matching order, of course). The usual approach for this when you have a large dataset like you describe is to handle a chunk at a time (say around 1G) so you're not trying to have it all in memory at once. What you're trying to do without a pretty solid grasp on C and some experience with BerkeleyDB is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing one or more commits/transactions. For example: start a transaction, do inserts, end transaction. That's a normal way to speed up database changes because it reduces the transaction overhead of independent SQL statements.

I'm not familiar with Berkely DB API, so it might have something better suited for bulk operations, just offering advice.

**Edit:**
Some links regarding transactions:
1. [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)
2. [Berkley DB Transaction Throughput](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/BerkeleyDB/ref/transapp/throughput.html)

Comment: Hi If we use transaction, our performance is better? What's the overhead of independent SQL statements ? can you explain me about it or give me some link so i can surf. Sorry about my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

The [Berkeley DB forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=271) are monitored by several Berkeley DB developers. That would be another good place to post such questions.

Comment: I had the same question but for C++. I've asked on the BDB forum here: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9315489&#9315489.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of C++ users, heres how to do it using the Berkeley C++ api, which is both undocumented, and has zero examples. It does work pretty well though!.

Create a Dbt (a database Thang, Im not making that up) to keep hold of a memory buffer:

void* buf = new unsigned char[bufferSize];
dbt = new Dbt;
dbt->set_data(buf);
dbt->set_ulen(bufferSize);
dbt->set_flags(DB_DBT_USERMEM);

Associate that with a DBMultipleKeyDataBuilder:

DBMultipleKeyDataBuilder* dbi=new DBMultipleKeyDataBuilder(dbt);

Append your Key and Value pairs one at a time until done or buffer full

dbi->append(curKeyBuf,curKeyLen,curDataBuf,curDataLen);
...(lots more of these)...

USe your DB* db, and a transaction if you wish in txn, and bulk write:
db->put(txn, dbt, NULL, DB_MULTIPLE_KEY );

delete dbi;

I've missed lots of detail, such as checking the buffer is full, or big enough to hold even one KV pair.

A DBMultipleKeyDataBuilder can only be used once, but a really efficient implementation will keep a pool of buffer Dbt objects and reuse them. You can use these Dbts for bulk reading as well, so a common pool of them can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk loading a hash in Berkeley DB has been a problem in the past. The following paper explores this further and suggests an algorithm to speed it up. The suggested algorithm sorts the data in a way linear hash (in Berkeley DB) expects hence loading can be done in one scan of the sorted data. This scales very well for large datasets. 
  Davood Rafiei, Cheng Hu, Bulk Loading a Linear Hash File, Proc. of the DaWak Conference, 2006.
  https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~drafiei/papers/dawak06.pdf